# python external function call alsaaudio lib

Tags: python, python-import

the test Code is:
1) the python script that work(extracted for a test):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import alsaaudio 
m = alsaaudio.Mixer('Digital')
m.setvolume(50)
```

2) PHP call Python:

```
echo shell_exec("/home/pi/test.py");
```

The Error(via apache):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/test.py", line 4, > 
>   in <'module'>
>       m = alsaaudio.Mixer('Digital') alsaaudio.ALSAAudioError: No such file or directory

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your questions requires you to edit it, add the code you tried, its output/expected output.

Comment: `File not found` means exactly what it says - in the context of `alsa`, it means the device `xxx` is not present in your system (in Unix, everything is a file).

Comment: sorry about that, with xxx i mean anything. In my case exactly alsaaudio.Mixer('Digital'), and ist works fine in the a.py.

Comment: I am having trouble with this. I list all available devices for alsaaudio with ```alsaaudio.pcms()```. I'm trying to control HDMI sound, but it just doesn't work. The same error appears here.